# A way to commit checkpoints manually in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark

We all know that in Spark Structured Streaming we can do

```
df.writeStream.foreachBatch(...).option("checkpointLocation", "path_here").start()
```

However, I have a use case where i would want to start the stream given the last checkpoint, do something with foreachBatch, **but do not commit the checkpoints at this** point, only to commit them later in my code (code that I can't run inside the above mentioned foreachBatch :)).

Has anyone have ever faced this demand and has found an adequate solution?